# how to set icon in file chooser dialog?

Tags: swing

I am asking a very simple question. How to add a icon to a file chooser dialog? 
I looked for an answer but couldn't find it. 
Is there any option for that?

Comment: "..I am asking a very simple question." - 'What is the meaning of life?' is another very simple question.  It is the *answer* that is complicated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on what you mean by "adding an icon".

If you mean display an icon for a particular file type, like this:
[image: Icons for gif files]

Then, have a look at [How to use File Chooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#fileview)

However, if what you really want is a preview of the file such as this:

[image: Image preview]

Then have a look at [Adding an accessory component](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#accessory). The accessory is a JComponent, so you can add a panel of additional controls if necessary. Here's an example of an [accessory control panel](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip93.html).